# Special characters in subject gmail api node.js

Tags: node.js, gmail

I'm trying to send an email using the gmail rest api, everything works fine except if I try to use special characters in the subject. I've tried different solutions that I've found around like:

[example1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44754770/1298902)

```
`Subject: =?utf-8?B?${email.subject.toString('base64')}?=\n\n` +
```

result from example 1
[image]

[example2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27698924/1298902)

```
`Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q? ${quotedPrintable.encode(utf8.encode(email.subject))}?=\n\n` +
```

result from example 2

[image]

This is the actual code:

```
const mail = Buffer.from(`From: ${from}\n` +
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n' +
    `To: ${to}\n` +
    `Cc: ${cc}\n` +
    `Bcc: ${bcc}\n` +
    `Subject: =?utf-8?B?${email.subject.toString('base64')}?=\n\n` +
    `${$.html()}`)
    .toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
```

```
  const response = await axios.post(`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/${from}/messages/send?access_token=${token}`, {
    raw: mail,
  });
```

This is a sample of the subject I want to send:

```
1 - = live unbound!!   que viva España
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can you provide the results of example1 and example2? 2. Is your current script using the method of "example1"? 3. Can you provide a sample value of the subject with the special characters?

Comment: @Tanaike I've updated the description to include the points you asked. My current script is just sending the subject without any coding, somethig like:

`Subject: ${email.subject}\n\n` +

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. But I noticed that your issue had been resolved. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for this problem

```
`Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?${quotedPrintable.encode(utf8.encode(email.subject))}?=\n\n`
```